# iPhone provisioning profile-Project and Target

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

At what place do I need to update any new provisioning profile, Project build settings or Target build settings?
I need to deploy the app on a device to test it.
Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Project setting is one per project. But a project can have multiple targets. Its helpful when you want same source code and just by changing some UI theme, you want a product for other client.

If you are having only one target then updating build setting will automatically update target setting.

If you are having multiple target, you should change target build settings for which you want to build a product.